# When hover, before content display on top of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I made social share button like NextWeb but i did not make it hover efects.

For example:

[Social icons look like this normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnMyO.png)

[When you hover looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2sCX.png)

How can i do this? I wanna display "Share on Twitter" block when hover that div.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood but I would go for something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      background-color: grey;
      padding: 20px;
      display: none;
    }

    span:hover + div {
      display: block;
    }

    .example {
       color: white;
       font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Hover over me!</span>
  <div class="example">I will show on hover</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the style elements in a css of course. What do you think ?